# xAxis ticks in Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, chartkick

I created a chart of User registered/Month chart with Chartkick, however, some data at xAxis is not visible, such as this:

[image: figure 1]

Aralık means "December" and Şubat means "February". Even though there aret users registered at "November", there is no representing label in xAxis.  There should be a label for every month, however I could not achieve it. My current rails code is this:

```
<%= line_chart User.group_by_month(:created_at).count %>
```

and the output from grouping query is this:

```
{Sun, 01 Nov 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>1, Tue, 01 Dec 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>1, Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>1, Mon, 01 Feb 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>1, Tue, 01 Mar 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>1}
```

I've also tried using the Google Charts library like this,

```
{library: {discrete: true, hAxis: {format: "MMMM yyyy", ticks: @patient_month_distribution.keys}}}
```

Google Charts outputs this error:

[image]

How can I modify my code so that every month/year is visible?

Comment: `ticks` are only available on a _Continuous_ axis -- but I don't think that is causing the error -- [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27591214/5090771) _might_ help...

Comment: @WhiteHat It does not work with continuous neither. Going to take a look at your link, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use format in group_by_month function

```
<%= line_chart User.group_by_month(:created_at, format: "%b %y").count %>
```